# creating database tables through JSP form using Spring MVC,JPA and performing CRUD operations on it

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa, crud

I was trying this and in the process I understood that I have to create dynamically classes as well which is quite impossible I felt. If someone has any experience of developing such code fragment please share

Comment: Actually the scenerio is like I will have one JSP and one controller and with the help of them I should be able to create as many tables a user wants

Answer (score 0):

Once you create your Entities, the other thing that you will need is to create JPA interfaces extending the crud repository, this is a very good guide that will help you with a simple example to get started:

http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/